# draggable + sortable working not so good

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/268By/

I'm trying to drag table rows from one table to another and to be able to also sort them in the second one.

the sorting doesn't work as it should(doesn't show the space where it will drop) and it works only between the rows tried to drag one more time after dropping them

Answer (score 0):

maybe try sorting the tr instead of the whole table?

$("#dropt table tbody ***tr***").sortable().disableSelection();